# Can you get the Master Sword with yellow hearts?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I want to get the Master Sword before taking on Vah Medoh, but I only have 9 hearts. I do have Mipha's Grace, and if it activates, it gives me 5 more yellow hearts. Can I pull out the Master Sword with this combination, or do all of the hearts have to be red?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, only the red hearts count.

From the [Prima guide](https://www.primagames.com/games/legend-zelda-breath-wild/tips/legend-zelda-breath-wild-master-sword-how-get-legendary-weapon):

> To get the Master Sword you need a total of 13 hearts. Any additional hearts you get from food or other abilities do not count toward the 13-heart total. You have to have 13 hearts as Link’s base health to pull the Master Sword from the ground.

Comment: I can confirm this; I tried it first time with extra yellow hearts, but they don't show on the counter.